# How to rotate to another face of 3d cube when swiped right

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, gesture

I created a 3d cube using SceneKit and added a gesture to recognize swiping right. But, I do not know how to rotate the cube to another face when swiped right. I do not want the cube to rotate continuously when swiped, only moving to another face that is on the right side. Sorry for any confusions.

Here is my code where I created cube:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
// UI
@IBOutlet weak var geometryLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!
// Geometry
var geometryNode: SCNNode = SCNNode()

// Gestures
var currentAngle: Float = 0.0

// MARK: Lifecycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)

// MARK: Scene

sceneSetup()


}

func sceneSetup() {

    let scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = false
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 25)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    var geometries = [
        SCNBox(width: 8.0, height: 8.0, length: 8.0, chamferRadius: 1.0)
    ]

    var materials = [SCNMaterial]()

    for i in 1...6 {
        let material = SCNMaterial()

        if i == 1 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red:0.02, green:0.98, blue:0.98, alpha:1.0) }
        if i == 2 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red:0.02, green:0.98, blue:0.98, alpha:1.0) }
        if i == 3 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red:0.02, green:0.98, blue:0.98, alpha:1.0) }
        if i == 4 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red:0.02, green:0.98, blue:0.98, alpha:1.0) }
        if i == 5 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red:0.02, green:0.98, blue:0.98, alpha:1.0) }
        if i == 6 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red:0.02, green:0.98, blue:0.98, alpha:1.0) }

        materials.append(material)
    }

    for i in 0..<geometries.count {
        let geometry = geometries[i]
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)

        node.geometry?.materials = materials

        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }


    let swipeRight: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture(gesture:)))
    swipeRight.direction = .right
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


}
```

Function for swipe right gesture when recognize:

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {


    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {


        switch swipeGesture.direction {

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:

                print("Swiped Right")

            default:

                break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which node you want to rotate?

Comment: Animating an `SCNTransaction` of rotation of your root node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `SCNAction.rotate` getting the current w value of the node rotation and adding the amount of angle you want, using this 2 extensions for converting to Radians and from Radians, replace my self.shipNode by your cube node, and change the axis if you need to, taking in account that the first 0 in the `SCNVector4Make` sentence is X axis

This is an example

```
extension Int {
    var degreesToRadians: Double { return Double(self) * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Double { return Double(self) * 180 / .pi }
}

extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

@objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    //here we rotate the ship node 30 grades in the Y axis each time
    self.shipNode?.runAction(SCNAction.rotate(toAxisAngle: SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, (self.shipNode?.rotation.w)! + Float(30.degreesToRadians)), duration: 1))
}
```

To rotate down you only have to change the axis of the rotation
**you can use this**

```
- (void) handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognize
{

     [self.ship runAction:[SCNAction rotateToAxisAngle:SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, [self getRadiansFromAngle:[self getAngleFromRadian:self.ship.rotation.w] + 30]) duration:1]];
}
```

**UPDATED**
**Using your code**
You need to use `SCNAction.rotate(by: #Float, around: #SCNVector3, duration: #duration)` method instead, below is the full code for your requeriments

```
@objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {


        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {


            switch swipeGesture.direction {

                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:

                    print("Swiped Right")

                geometryNode.runAction(SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat(90.degreesToRadians), around: SCNVector3Make(0, 1, 0), duration: 0.2))


                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:

                    print("Swiped Left")
                    geometryNode.runAction(SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat(-90.degreesToRadians), around: SCNVector3Make(0, 1, 0), duration: 0.2))

                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:

                    print("Swiped Down")
                   geometryNode.runAction(SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat(90.degreesToRadians), around: SCNVector3Make(1, 0, 0), duration: 0.2))
                default:

                    break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I also added one for swipe left just by setting degree to negative. How would I do this for swipe down? Thanks!

Comment: @Andy check my answer was updated for your las requirement

Comment: Hey, it works. But, when I do a swipe down and then a swipe left or right, it does a weird rotation. Like it will do the swipe down but then it doesn’t rotate to the face right next to it when doing swipe down and right. I think it has to do something with the angle at which it is turned. Can you help me fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is related to the fact that you start a movement and after that before is over start another in a different direction, you can handle this by two ways one blocking one action when the other is executing or two combining those actions @Andy if you can share with me the code in Github to help you with your real project

Comment: I have released the code on Github. The link is: https://github.com/AndyJiang05/3d-Cube. I hope you understand what my problem is, if not you can just launch the app and see it for yourself. Thanks for all your help! The code is under ViewController

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: @Andy I will help you tomorrow bro, today is holidays

Comment: @Andy my answer was updated, let me know, best regards and merry Christmas